# Transfer Functions of filters

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image][image]

Please I need help identifying the type of filter this is. I just could not work my way from the function to the type. Not just identifying it, I need help with how to work back and forth on any filter. Thanks a lot

@Tyler I just uploaded a picture. How do I go from here.

Comment: I just uploaded a picture. Kindly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1) Your first result is

$$
\frac{V_{out}(j\omega)}{V_{in}(j\omega)}=1 \Bigg\rvert_{\omega=0}
$$

i.e., at low frequencies you have \$V_{out} = V_{in} = 0\,dB\$ (the input signal is not attenuated).

Hint 2) For the case

$$
\frac{V_{out}(j\omega)}{V_{in}(j\omega)}\Bigg\rvert_{\omega=\infty}
$$

use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate the function's limit as ω tends to infinity:

$$
\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \frac{V_{out}(j\omega)}{V_{in}(j\omega)}
$$